# How to show image color depth in Eye of Gnome?

Tags: 12.04

There seem to be no way to obtain the color depth info (32/24/8 bit) of an image being displayed. Is there plugin for that? If you have any recommendation for better image viewer that has such feature, feel free to post

Answer (score 1):

They are not about EoG, but I found 1 way to get the information of  color depth (or bit depth).

**Using `mediainfo` comannd**

```
mediainfo "image_file_name" | grep 'Bit depth'
```

It will be displayed as follows:

```
Bit depth     : 32 bits
```